# What does minimum entropy deconvolution mean?

Tags: filters, signal-detection

I want to use minimum entropy deconvolution method to analyse vibration signals to detect bearing characteristic fault frequencies. I am confused as to what the meaning or exact definition of minimum entropy deconvolution is.

Comment: Hi Karima, this might be a bit broad, because we can't know what your background is, and what you do not understand about the hundreds of results you find when you ask a search engine about "minimum entropy deconvolution". Maybe you could base your question on what you're already understanding instead of asking us to write a book or reproduce the original 1978 paper?

Comment: thank you  Marcus Müller for your response I have read this paper, and the basic equation but what means exactly entropy and minimum entropy!

Comment: well, you're looking to find an "optimal" inverse mapping to your unknown convolution. IN MED, you define "optimal" as "minimizes the statistical entropy of the result". Since the definitions of entropy in information theory and in statistical mechanics just differ in a constant prefactor, that's the same as minimizing *Shannon entropy*.